# Czech republic population income dataset

Tags: europe, income

I have to collect stastics on:

1. Population income by region of Czech Republic
2. Crime data
3. Real estate prices

I tried opendata.cz but they don't provide these data.
Perhaps there is an EU data portal where this kind of data might reside.